# SQL Server Prepared Statement saying invalid column count

Tags: php, sql-server

So I'm working on this project here and I"m trying to do a prepared statement so I can handle any odd objects like slashes and what not as the raw data comes through. However, when I go to execute the statement it provides the same error over and over again:

```
SQLSTATE: 07002
code: 0
message: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]COUNT field incorrect or syntax error
```

it says that my field count is incorrect, but I checked all the variables and made sure everything that was supposed to be there, is. So I'm just a little confused I guess. Also to note this is my first time working with the sqlsrv prepared statements, so any help would be awesome!

Here is my code below:

```
<?php
    $serverName = "localhost"; 
    $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"devel", "UID"=>"root", "PWD"=>"");
    $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
    $error_message = "";
    $xml = trim(file_get_contents('/file.xml'));
    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
    $truck_number;
    $date_time;
    $speed;
    $heading;
    $gps_quality;
    $latitude;
    $longitude;
    $location;
    $fix_type;
    $ignition;
    $gps_odometer;
    $gps_rolling_odometer;
    $performx_odometer;
    $performx_fuel;
    $performx_speed;
    $performx_idle;
    $packet_id;


    sqlsrv_begin_transaction($conn);
    $error_count = 0;
    $q = "INSERT INTO eagle_devel.dbo.people_net (truck_number, date_time, speed, heading, gps_quality, latitude, longitude, location, fix_type, ignition, gps_odometer, gps_rolling_odometer,
                 performx_odometer, performx_fuel, performx_speed, performx_idle, packet_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";       
    $stmt = sqlsrv_prepare($conn, $q, array(&$truck_number, &$date_time, &$speed, &$heading, &$gps_quality, &$latitude, &$longitude, &$location, &$fix_type, &$ignition, &$gps_odometer, &$gps_rolling_odometer, &$performx_odometer, &$performx_fuel, &$performx_speed, &$performx_idle, &$packet_id));
    foreach($xml->loc_history as $loc_history){
            $truck_number = $loc_history->truck_number;
            $date_time = $loc_history->datetime;
            $speed = $loc_history->speed;
            $heading = $loc_history->heading;
            $gps_quality = $loc_history->gps_quality;
            $latitude = $loc_history->latitude;
            $longitude = $loc_history->longitude;
            $location = $loc_history->location;
            $fix_type = $loc_history->fix_type;
            $ignition = $loc_history->ignition;
            $gps_odometer = $loc_history->gps_odometer;
            $gps_rolling_odometer = $loc_history->gps_rolling_odometer;
            $performx_odometer = $loc_history->performx_odometer;
            $performx_fuel = $loc_history->performx_fuel;
            $performx_speed = $loc_history->performx_speed;
            $performx_idle = $loc_history->performx_idle;
            $packet_id = $xml->packet_id;   


            if(sqlsrv_execute($stmt) === false){
                $error_count++;
                if(($errors = sqlsrv_errors()) != null){
                    foreach($errors as $error){
                        $error_message .= "SQLSTATE: ".$error['SQLSTATE']."<br>";
                        $error_message .= "code: ".$error['code']."<br>";
                        $error_message .= "message: ".$error['message']."<br><br>";
                    }
                }
            }
    }
    if($error_count)
        sqlsrv_rollback($conn);
    else
        sqlsrv_commit($conn);

    print $error_message;
?>
```

UPDATE : I was told to try and initialize the variables before hand so I did and I get this.

```
SQLSTATE: IMSSP
code: -16
message: An invalid PHP type for parameter 1 was specified.
```

I have no idea what this means so I'm researching.

Comment: Before calling `sqlsrv_execute($stmt)` get the value of $stmt and try running it directly against your database.  Does it work?  Are all of the column names correct?

Comment: that's what I was doing before hand, and yes the column names are correct. I also checked to see if I missed one as well and there was nothing missed

Comment: Have you tried initializing the variables before the `sqlsrv_prepare` statement?

Comment: Is `$loc_history->datetime` correct or should that be date_time?

Comment: that is correct I switched it to date_time for the table

Comment: I don't see anything obvious.  You may want to try explicitly setting the column data types, as shown here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc626305%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Comment: yeah I'm not sure either

Comment: You may also want to try adding values in your variable initializations just to see if it makes a difference (for example `$truck_number = 0;`)

Comment: that did not work either

Comment: I just noticed your update indicating this error: `An invalid PHP type for parameter 1 was specified.`  Did you look at the value of $truck_number after this statement: `$truck_number = $loc_history->truck_number;`?  Is it the appropriate type for the  `eagle_devel.dbo.people_net.truck_number` column?